# Does TFslim TFExampleDecoder also support decoding sequence example?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Does TFslim [TFExampleDecoder](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/data/tfexample_decoder.py) also support decoding sequence examples?

If not, how easy do you think it will be to derive a child class to support it?

Comment: You mean one that decodes the [SequenceExample](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto#L292)?

Comment: @drpng, Yes, that one

Comment: Sounds like it would be a welcome contribution. Feel free to file an issue on our github page or submit a PR directly.